# Disable a Windows Server 2016 network interface when the computer is not in use

Tags: networking, windows-server-2016

I'm trying to modify my server (Running Windows Server 2016 Datacenter with GUI) so that when it's not in use or has been idle for a while, the network interface shuts down (Gets offline). How can I do that? (My network interface name is Ethernet0)

Comment: Usually it's the other way around - use the network interface to turn on a system (Wake on LAN). What's the trigger to turn the interface back on?

Comment: @spacenomyous That's not my issue. I want it to happen. I want the interface to go offline when the system is idle.

Comment: Forgive me for the questions, this goes against the entire premise of a "server". We design entire enterprises around high-availability designs with redundancy and fault-tolerance. To willfully configure a system to turn off when it's "idle", with no trigger to turn back on, is asinine. Why not just disable the NIC and turn it on when you need it?

Comment: My apologies for being so blunt, and for repeating the sentiments that spacenomyous has already stated, but this is antithetical to what a server is and what a server is intended to be.

Answer (score 0):

disable: `netsh set interface name="Ethernet0" admin=DISABLED`

enable: `netsh set interface name="Ethernet0" admin=ENABLED`

(For what it's worth...)

Comment: I'm wondering how to determine what an idle NIC is... Use perf counters for network traffic plus time? Trigger to turn back on at certain time of day?

The real question is why... lol